# Am I missing some configuration properties?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-14.04

Hello I have an issue with my server configuration,

I have **Ubuntu 14.04** and **Apache 2.4.7**, the problem is something is bad configurated .

I have five domains, dom1.com, dom2.com,dom3.com, etc. The problem is two domains redirect to an old domain that i am not used any more, and the others show the index.xml at dom1.com.

So I dont now what could be.The result is when i made a request at navigator always respond with Building Site 1, in case

```
/var/www/dom1/index.html --> Building Site 1
/var/www/dom2/index.html --> Building Site 2
/var/www/dom3/index.html --> Building Site 3
/var/www/dom4/index.html --> Building Site 4
/var/www/dom5/index.html --> Building Site 5
```

An at Apache:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/dom1.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.dom1.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dom1
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the same for the ohers domains.

And at /etc/hosts I defing the for each domain the pair ip domain

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu.myhosted.com       ubuntu

::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX dom1.com
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX dom2.com
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX dom3.com
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX dom4.com
XXX.XX.XXX.XXX dom5.com
```

Am I missing some configuration properties?

Comment: I don't know how did you manage to have multiple domain sites configured. It would be worth taking a look at your VirtualHost settings.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be configuring different domains. You're accessing `dom1.com` (according to the hosts file), but your Apache config only has `www.dom1.com`. **These are different names.**

Since Apache can't find a virtual host section for `dom1.com` it gives up and just shows the first vhost, whatever it is.

Either fix the ServerName parameters, or add the non-www name as a ServerAlias (if you want both variants to work).